# Access all child values of a snapshot in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase Realtime Database.
I want to read memberRollNo , and memberMobileNo of the node whose name(key) is equal to nname. I am only able to read memberRollNo with my code and Textview for memberMobileNo shows out to be blank.

```
 DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DBRef.child("Members").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String roll = dataSnapshot.child(nname).child("memberRollNo").getValue(String.class);
                DRollNo.setText(roll);


                String mob = dataSnapshot.child(nname).child("memberMobile").getValue(String.class);
                DMobile.setText(mob);


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

DRollNo and DMobile are textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
String mob = dataSnapshot.child(nname).child("memberMobile").getValue(String.class);
```

into this:

```
 String mob = dataSnapshot.child(nname).child("memberPhone").getValue(String.class);
```

In your database, you do not have a child called `memberMobile`. The name inside the method `child()` needs to be the same as in the database to be able to retrieve it.